# Read geotiff files alttitude using GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff

I am using GDAL to read a geotiff file.

I would like to read the coordinate Z of my geotiff file.

has anyone worked on a case before ?

Regard,

Comment: What have you tried so far? What has worked and what hasn't? What have you searched for? What have your found? Stack Overflow works better if you bring a specific programming question. General questions, such as this, tend to produce unsatisfactory answers.

Comment: I have managed to read the elavation

Comment: Excellent. I see that you have answered your own question. That's good. If that turns out to be the best answer, please accept your own answer. If your answer is insufficient, please update your question to more specifically describe your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read elevation using gdal python from geotiff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956653/read-elevation-using-gdal-python-from-geotiff)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to read the elavation from osgeo import gdal

```
gdal.UseExceptions()

ds = gdal.Open('test_data.tif')
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
elevation = band.ReadAsArray()

print elevation.shape
print elevation
```